# Saving to ManyToManyFields using ModelForm and ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, modelform

I've created a basic Django app that contains books/authors/publishers as per the Django Book - trying to use a ModelForm to create a means to modify existing books - the problem is that the 'authors' field is a ManyToManyField and when I choose a choice on the ModelForm it simply wipes the existing selection and doesn't save the new one?

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField2(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

    authors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.all(), required=False)
```

views.py

```
def editBook(request, b=None):
    instance = None
    if b is not None:
        instance = Book.objects.get(title=b)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = BookForm(instance=instance)
    return render_to_response('book_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Cheers!

**edit**
I have just found several articles that encourage the following in views.py

```
authors = form.save(commit=False)
authors.user = request.user
authors.save()
form.save_m2m()
```

But still not having any luck - can't be this hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to override the save method in the ModelForm:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    authors =[]
    for a in self.cleaned_data['authors']:
         authors.append(Author.objects.get(first_name=t.first_name))

    b = super(BookForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    for a in authors:
        b.authors.add(a)
    b.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you override `authors` field. Either don't do it and let Django do it's job, or handle it manually.

Comment: How exactly do you handle it manually? Apologies for nub questions but  been struggling for a while with this!

Comment: @jonseager Why do you need this? Just remove this `authors = ...` line and everything will work as you want.

Comment: I removed it a while back - it's still not saving. The form is read correctly cos I can output the cleaned_data to the shell and it shows the author - but yet still doesn't actually save? Thanks for your help!